# Does having hundreds of saga cause any performance issues in React application?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I came across a React application that contains ~200 sagas, each watching for several patterns (Action types). I was thinking if having this amount of sagas impacts the app in any negative way, whether it's performance or loading times.

Why I think so? Each saga is listening for many patterns throughout the lifetime of the application, so they are more like the event listeners, but they never got removed from the app until it is closed.

If there are issues with having lots of sagas, then how the enterprise/big apps are handling this situation because they definitely will have more sagas than me.

I know there is a way of loading sagas dynamically based on the requirement, but not sure if that's the best solution.

The root saga looks like this

```js
function * rootSaga () {
  yield all(sagas.map(saga => fork(saga))) // sagas = array of 200 sagas
}
```

Comment: It depends on many things. The new (ish) version of react dev tools includes a performance meter. Give it a try! Like they say, profile before you optimise.

Comment: At my job we run easily ~1000 watcher sagas at the same time and the impact is negligible. Of course if you have some crazy pattern functions that might be different, but in general normal javascript operations are rarely the source of perf. problems.